# Adobe Flash Recorder Not Showing Video

Tags: adobe, webcam, flash, wowza

I'm using Adobe Flash to record live video and stream to a Wowza Media Server. Everything has worked before on all browsers on Mac, and PC. But right now, for one of my employees who's using a PC, a bug has come up on Chrome (version 23), Flash (version 11).

Essentially, the entire .swf object is visible except the area where you should be able to see yourself -- a white screen takes its place. When I record a video of myself talking and play it back, I can only hear audio; I can't see video. And when I leave the website, his webcam stays on.

When he restarts his computer, and uses either Firefox or Skype first, and then switches to Chrome, everything's fine. But when he goes on our product and our .swf object is the first program to access his webcam, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the Pepper Flash player in Chrome has struck again.  Pepper Flash is Adobe and Google's attempt to keep flash player alive on linux platforms. Unfortunately, as a result, all users of Chrome (regardless of their OS) have to deal with Pepper Flash's bugs.

You can, however, disable Pepper Flash in Chrome by going to this url: `chrome://plugins`

Look for the Adobe Flash plugin, you will likely find that there are several installed. Find the one that has "pepper" in the path and disable that plugin.  Your user's problem will likely go away.